# Mapstruct - ignore field for the whole mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is there any possibility to ignore some field, eg `@Mapping(ignore = true, target = "dontWantToLazyFetchFromDbSometimes")`? I have mapper where sometimes the common object has list of objects and that list is sometimes unnecessary. I want to prevent unnecessary fetching data from db when someone forget to add `ignore` when adding some new mapping method:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ModelMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "aaa", source = "bbb")
    @Mapping(ignore = true, target = "ccc")
    ResultObject mapToResultObject(Window window);

    @Mapping(target = "aaa", source = "bbb")
    @Mapping(target= "ccc", source= "ccc")
    ResultObject mapToResultObject(Window window);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you need to use [shared configuration](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations):

```
@MapperConfig(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface IgnoreCccConfig {

    // Not intended to be generated, but to carry inheritable mapping annotations:
    @Mapping(target = "ccc", ignore = "true")
    ResultObject any(Window window);

}
```

ModelMapper:

```
@Mapper(config = IgnoreCccConfig.class, componentModel = "spring")
public interface ModelMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "aaa", source = "aaa")
    ResultObject mappingMethod1(Window window);

    @Mapping(target = "aaa", source = "bbb")
    ResultObject mappingMethod2(Window window);

}
```

in this case both methods are ignoring ccc target field.